# center of quotients of $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Does there exist a non-unital $C^*$ algebra  $A$ such that $\mathcal{Z}(A/I)\neq 0$,where $ \mathcal{Z}(A/I)$ denotes the center of the $A/I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. There are non-unital commutative C$^*$-algebras, like $C_0(\mathbb R)$. Any quotient of it will be commutative and nonzero if the ideal is non-trivial.